# Scala: Self types in Constructors for generic classes

Tags: c#, scala, generics

Here's a taste of the C# code that I'm porting into Scala. No need to worry about the details.

```
public class GridBase<HexT, SideT, UnitT, SegT> : IGridBase
    where HexT : Hex
    where SideT : Side
    where UnitT : Unit
    where SegT : ISeg
{
  public GridBase(Geometry<HexT, SideT, UnitT, SegT> geom, IGridBase orig)
  {
  this.geom = geom;
  }
}

public class Scen: Descrip<HexC, SideC, UnitC>, IListsGeom<HexC, SideC, UnitC>
{
    public Geometry<HexC, SideC, UnitC, ISegC> geomC;
    public override IGeom iGeom { get { return geomC; } }
    public HexCList hexCs { get; private set; }
    public override HexList<HexC> hexs { get { return hexCs; } }
    public SideCList sideCs { get; private set; }
    public override SideList<SideC> sides { get { return sideCs; } }   
    public UnitCList unitCs { get; private set; }
    public override KeyList<UnitC> units { get { return unitCs; } }
}
```

As Martin Odersky has pointed out the problem with generics is that the number of type parameters references and their restraint references tend to explode. However for the GridBase class, I need to resolve the types via generics rather than by abstract types. So I want to be able to get multiple types out of one type parameter. So in Scala I create a trait for my types:

```
abstract class Hex(val num1: Int){} //These are declared in their own files
abstract class Side {val sideString = "This is a side"}

trait DescripTypes //separate file
{
  type HexT <: Hex
  type SideT <: Side
}

class ScenTypes extends DescripTypes //separate file
{ //This is an ex of an implemntation of the above in a different package
  type HexT = HexC
  type SideT = SideC
}
```

Then I create my Gridbase class using a self type

```
class GridBase[T <: DescripTypes](val myHex: HexT) extends DescripTypes
{//Compiler doesn't recognise the HexT type in the constructor  
  other: DescripTypes =>
  type other = T  

  var testvar = 5   //The rest does nothing at useful at the moment
  var testvar2 = "" //just for testing
  def mymethod(var1: HexT) //Compiler recognises HexT
  {
    testvar += var1.num1 //This compiles fine
  }
  def method2(var1: SideT) //Compiler recognises SideT
  {
    testvar2 = var1.sideString //This compiles fine
  }
```

}

For some reason I can't seem to use the type members of DescripTypes in the GridBase Class constructor, although I can use them fine inside the class body. Any help appreciated. But also is this the best way to get multiple types out of one type parameter?

Clarification: All Classes are in separate files. No inner classes here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `T#HexT` in the constructor?

`#` is called a [type projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala), and used to refer to inner types. I'm not solid in the terminology so would not go into details, but as a guideline you use `A#B` when performing type-level operations (see also [type lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits)), while `A.B` is related to [path-dependent types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976791/is-a-path-dependent-type-a-subtype).

Note: When `A` is a package or object, then `A.B` behaves as you would expect, the `#` fun comes into play with traits or classes.

While not directly related, this might prove to be a good read: [Independently Extensible Solutions to the Expression Problem](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/papers/IC_TECH_REPORT_200433.pdf)

Comment: Ok, might be directly related. But I left pondering on that as an excercise :)

Comment: Well Great that to seems to work, but I've got no idea why. The only documentation ref to the # operator I can find is for inner-outer classes.

Comment: Surprisingly the term 'type projection' doesn't seem to appear in Odersky et al's book.

Answer (score 2):

It’s of course hard to guess but I think your class should *maybe* (you’d have to change quite a bit to make it actually work) look like this

```
class GridBase[T <: DescripTypes](val myHex: T#HexT) { this: T =>
  var testvar = 5
  var testvar2 = ""
  def mymethod(var1: HexT) {
    testvar += var1.num1
  }
  def method2(var1: SideT) {
    testvar2 = var1.sideString
  }
}
```

In your example `mymethod` takes any `HexT` whereas I think you want to restrict it to the same outer class that `myHex` has.

Depending on the use-case, (the self-type requires you to mix-in a sub-trait of `DescripTypes`), the following is more appropiate:

```
class GridBase[T <: DescripTypes](val myHex: T#HexT) {
  var testvar = 5
  var testvar2 = ""
  def mymethod(var1: T#HexT) {
    testvar += var1.num1
  }
  def method2(var1: T#SideT) {
    testvar2 = var1.sideString
  }
}
```

You’d have to specify the subclass of `DescripTypes` and could then use the type aliases defined in these subclasses.

```
val scenType = new ScenTypes
val scenTypeHex = new scenType.HexT
val scenTypeSide = new scenType.SideT
val gb_st = new GridBase[ScenTypes](scenTypeHex)
gb_st.mymethod(scenTypeHex)
gb_st.method2(scenTypeSide)

// and the same for some other subclass of DescribTypes
val scenType2 = new ScenTypes2
val scenType2Hex = new scenType2.HexT
val scenType2Side = new scenType2.SideT
val gb_st2 = new GridBase[ScenTypes2](scenType2Hex)
gb_st2.mymethod(scenType2Hex)
gb_st2.method2(scenType2Side)

// Does not compile:
gb_st2.method2(scenTypeSide)
```

Comment: Hopefully edit has clarified. I don't think there's any inner classes here. The examples are not that useful as they don't return a specific type.

Comment: Thanks that "this: T =>" is neater.

Comment: @RichOliver DescripTypes#HexT is an abstract inner type